# Assigning vector of vector of string with vector of string

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, vector, stl

I want to fill vector of vector of string with different vector of strings.But it is not being filled and same empty values are there which are initialized during definition.

```
int A = 3;
vector<string> s(A);
vector<vector<string>> st(A , vector<string> (A));
  for(int i = 0; i < A;i++)
    for(int j =0; j<A;j++)
        s[i][j] = '.';

st.at(0) =s;
vector<string> ss(A) ;
ss = st[0];
for(int i = 0; i < A;i++)
    for(int j =0; j<A;j++)
        cout<<ss[i][j];
```

Output is empty.

Comment: Take a look at whether `s` is empty at this point in which you do `st.at(0) =s;`

Comment: @TheUndeadFish I have checked the same by printing.s is not empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's walk through the code here:

```
int A = 3;
/*1*/ vector<string> s(A);
/*2*/ vector<vector<string>> st(A , vector<string> (A));
/*3*/   for(int i = 0; i < A;i++)
/*4*/     for(int j =0; j<A;j++)
/*5*/         s[i][j] = '.';
```

On the line marked "1", you create a vector (`s`) of three empty strings.
On the line marked "2", you create a vector (`st`) containing three vectors, each of which contains 3 empty strings.

In the loop on lines 3-5, you try to assign a character to position 0..2 of each of the strings in `s`. But that is beyond the end of the strings, so this is undefined behavior.

After the undefined behavior, all bets are off.

Comment: Understood. When I check the size also it is still 3 empty strings but when I print with two for loops,it prints 9 dots ('.').I don't understand this behaviour.

Comment: The behavior is *undefined*. That means that the standard puts no restrictions on what it can do. It could do different things each time you run it. It could format your hard disk.

Comment: Understood,Thanks